# Navisworks in Model Derivative renders auxiliar shapes

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-model-derivative, autodesk-navisworks

I have an IFC file with some concrete slabs that I run through a parser that returns me the geometries for all the IFC elements inside. The parser is done by using the [IfcOpenShell](http://ifcopenshell.org/) library. When I use that, I get the geometries correctly in a comfortable .ply or .obj format. These geometries are correct: 
[Element geometry well parsed, a simple solid done by extruding a closed are](https://i.stack.imgur.com/szDQ3.png)

However, when importing the same IFC to Autodesk Viewer via Forge Model Derivative with the Navisworks importer, issues start to happen:

[The viewer renders extra elements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PSPb6.png)

What it's happening is that now the elements used to generate the element are also being rendered. In this case, the inner curve of the element is done by using an arch of a basic circle, which gets rendered.

Why is this happening?

Comment: Since you specifically mention the use of Model Derivative service with Navisworks importer, I assume you are aware of the [switch to Revit](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/model-derivative-ifc-pipeline-call-change), right? What output do you see when you switch to Revit importer? If you still see issues even with the new importer, I can reach out to the Model Derivative dev team and ask for more details.

Comment: Also, if you wouldn't mind sharing the IFC file with us, the dev team would probably appreciate having a sample file that can reproduce the issue. Could you share the file via some 3rd party service like Dropbox and send us a link to: forge (dot) help (at) autodesk (dot) com?

Comment: I am afraid I can not share the file, as it falls under a NDA, I will try to generate a file with the conflicting element. Regarding the swtich, using the new importer gives me far better results, but some elements present weird artifacts with the faces.